# Show Enum Description Instead of Name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, enums

I had databinding set up like this:

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={my:Enumeration {x:Type credit:OccupationCategory}}}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding EmplType}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
```

and it worked really well.  Do to a change in the larger software design I can no longer have anything that generates an INotifyPropertyChanged Event so that type of databinding doesn't work.  Instead I am manually setting the selectedIndex and building the options from code like this:

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResidenceOwnershipType}}"/>
```

which references

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ResidenceOwnershipType" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}" >
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="credit:ResidenceOwnershipType" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

That works as far as the building of the list options is concerned and the linking of all of my data, but I can't get the comboboxes to show the description tag in the enumeration instead of the actual text.

I've tried something like this:

```xml
DisplayMemberPath="Description"
```

but that wasn't correct.  How would I go about doing this?

EDIT:

My Enum:

```
[DataContract]
public enum ResidenceOwnershipType
{
    [Description("")]
    None = 0,
    [Description("Owns Home Outright")]
    OwnsHomeOutright = 1,
    [Description("Buying Home")]
    BuyingHome = 2,
    [Description("Renting/Leasing")] //Weird order here reflects RouteOne website
    RentingLeasing = 4,
    [Description("Living w/Relatives")]
    LivingWithRelatives = 3,
    [Description("Owns/Buying Mobile Home")]
    MobileHome = 5,
    [Description("Unknown")]
    Unknown = 6
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you keep this `ItemsSource` you will have to define a custom [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) as the `DisplayMemberPath` is just a path via which you will not be able to retrieve the description.

As for what the template should look like: You can bind a `TextBlock` to the enum value (the current `DataContext`) and pipe that through a [`ValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) using `Binding.Converter`. The code would just be some reflection to retrieve the `Description` (`GetType`, `GetCustomAttributes` etc.)

Alternatives are a custom method that return a usable collection right away (and is used in the `ObjectDataProvider`) or a custom [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) which does the same thing.

---

Method example if we are talking about a `ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute`:

```
public static class EnumUtility
{
    // Might want to return a named type, this is a lazy example (which does work though)
    public static object[] GetValuesAndDescriptions(Type enumType)
    {
        var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<object>();
        var valuesAndDescriptions = from value in values
                                    select new
                                        {
                                            Value = value,
                                            Description = value.GetType()
                                                .GetMember(value.ToString())[0]
                                                .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                                                .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
                                                .First()
                                                .Description
                                        };
        return valuesAndDescriptions.ToArray();
    }
}
```

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Data" MethodName="GetValuesAndDescriptions"
                    ObjectType="local:EnumUtility">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:TypeExtension TypeName="local:TestEnum" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Description"
         SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
```

Comment: There isn't a way to get that information in with the ObjectDataProvider?

Comment: @NathanTornquist: Only if you write a method which returns objects that contain the description as property or just the description as string if that is all you need, wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @NathanTornquist: You could also implement this as a [Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) and ditch the `ObjectDataProvider` (custom markup extensions are the solutions to most of my XAML problems).

Comment: From reading into it, it looks like writing a custom method would be the best solution.  Then I could replace GetValues with GetValuesAndDescription or something like that.  I don't really know how though.  Are you well enough versed in this that you could provide an example?

Comment: @NathanTornquist: You never specified what the description is, is it actually an attribute for enum values?

Comment: Yes.  I've added the actual enumeration above.  The old databinding logic was able to pull and display those descriptions.  It lets you make things look a lot nicer that way.

Comment: @NathanTornquist: Why don't you just take the code from the previous markup extension, also, **why do you need to throw that away anyway, it's pointless**? (See edit for example, though that probably does nothing different than the `my:Enumeration` markup extension)

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you.  And I had to throw away the old code because we changed from a system with local datamodels to a unified API.  I had to redesign the databinding based on limitations imposed by the new framework.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an addition on H.B.'s answer I implemented for my own application:

Check if the Description attribute is added:

```
Description = (value.GetType().GetMember(value.ToString())[0].GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Count() > 0 ? 
                                                value.GetType().GetMember(value.ToString())[0].GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DescriptionAttribute>().First().Description 
                                                : value)
```

And Set the following attribute to make sure the correct ID's are used: `SelectedValuePath="Value"`