# C# Strange ComboBox Data -- Visual Studio Issue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, list

I have databinding for my comboboxes set up like this: [Show Enum Description Instead of Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439920/show-enum-description-instead-of-name)

When I am trying to pull the data however, I can't just get the state code, such as IA. I get this long string like: { Value = IA, Description = Iowa }

When I pause the code and look at the combo box values, I am able to do stuff like State.SelectionBoxItem.Value  That is an option that expands from the popup menu when you hover over the variable. I can't seem to ever just grab that value programatically though.

Is it a "feature" of visual studio to allow me to break that list down like that?

Is that a string that I will have to break down programatically?

Comment: How are you trying to "pull" the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be you are looking at SelectedItem property not SelectedValue. The string  { Value = IA, Description = Iowa } is result of invocation of ToString method of an anonymous type, so yes it is a feature.

In code form another question SelectedValuePath property is not set to Value, which is required to get state code of ListBox selected item through SelectedValue property.

Comment: SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectionBoxItem all show the same thing. I realized that I could get the selectedvalue and cast it back to the enum I'm using.  That worked just fine.  Thanks for your answer though.