# How to set Enum to ItemsSource WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, enums

How can I set an Enum to a listbox in xaml. However in the listbox I need to display the Description not the name/value of the enum. And then I when I click a button I need the selected enum to be passed in a method via icommand as an enum not a string. 
For example:

```
  public enum MyEnum 
  {
     EnumOne = 0,
     [Description("Enum One")]
     EnumTwo = 1,
     [Description("Enum Two")]
     EnumTwo = 2,
     [Description("Enum Three")]
  }
```

Need to bind these enums to a listbox with a displaymemberpath of the description. And then upon a selection in the listbox, pass in the selected enum like so:

```
  private void ButtonDidClick(MyEnum enum)
  {

  }
```

XAML:

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyEnum"} /> ?
```

And I know how to do the rest as far as wiring up a command to a button..etc.. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I use convert it to a Dictionary<enum,string>  and use Value as the DisplayMember

Comment: I think this answer does what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439920/show-enum-description-instead-of-name

Comment: That was a nice example. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a production app
Got this off SO a while ago and cannot find the source
Bind the DisplayMememberPath to Value

```
public static Dictionary<T, string> EnumToDictionary<T>()
    where T : struct
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);

    // Can't use generic type constraints on value types,
    // so have to do check like this
    if (enumType.BaseType != typeof(Enum))
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be of type System.Enum");
    Dictionary<T, string> enumDL = new Dictionary<T, string>();
    foreach (T val in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
    {
        enumDL.Add(val, val.ToString());
    }
    return enumDL;
}
```

#### GetDescription Method

For those who want to know how to read the description attribute value. The following can easily be converted to use `enum` or into an extenstion. I found this implementation is more flexible.

Using this method, replace `val.ToString()` with `GetDescription(val)`.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the value of the 'Description' attribute; otherwise, returns null.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetDescription(object value)
    {
        string sResult = null;

        FieldInfo oFieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        if (oFieldInfo != null)
        {
            object[] oCustomAttributes = oFieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);

            if ((oCustomAttributes != null) && (oCustomAttributes.Length > 0))
            {
                sResult = ((DescriptionAttribute)oCustomAttributes[0]).Description;
            }
        }
        return sResult;
    }
```

Comment: Very nice, worked great. However I needed the value in the dictionary to be the description of the enum not the value, so I had previously wrote a GetDescription(this enum value) function that returns the descriptions so I just called that function in the enumDL.Add() and passed in the value as an enum. Works great, thanks for help

Answer (score 6):

Use ObjectDataProvider:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="enumValues"
   MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
      <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
           <x:Type TypeName="local:ExampleEnum"/>
      </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
 </ObjectDataProvider>
```

and then bind to static resource:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource enumValues}}"
```

Found this solution [here](https://druss.co/2015/01/wpf-binding-itemssource-to-enum/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by converting your Enum to a list of MyEnum-string tuples and using the DisplayMemberPath parameter of the ListBox to display the description item.  When you select a particular Tuple, just grab the MyEnum part of it, and use that to set the SelectedEnumValue property in the ViewModel.

Here's the code:

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EnumToListBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding EnumToDescriptions}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEnumToDescription}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Item2"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
               Text="{Binding SelectedEnumToDescription.Item2}"/>
</Grid>
```

The Code-Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel : PropertyChangedNotifier
{
    private List<Tuple<MyEnum, string>> _enumToDescriptions = new List<Tuple<MyEnum, string>>();
    private Tuple<MyEnum, string> _selectedEnumToDescription;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Array Values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
        foreach (var Value in Values)
        {
            var attributes = Value.GetType().GetField(Value.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            var attribute = attributes[0] as DescriptionAttribute;
            _enumToDescriptions.Add(new Tuple<MyEnum, string>((MyEnum)Value, (string)attribute.Description));
        }
    }

    public List<Tuple<MyEnum, string>> EnumToDescriptions
    {
        get
        {
            return _enumToDescriptions;
        }
        set
        {
            _enumToDescriptions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EnumToDescriptions");
        }
    }

    public Tuple<MyEnum, string> SelectedEnumToDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedEnumToDescription;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedEnumToDescription = value;
            SelectedEnumValue = _selectedEnumToDescription.Item1;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEnumToDescription");
        }
    }

    private MyEnum? _selectedEnumValue;
    public MyEnum? SelectedEnumValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedEnumValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedEnumValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEnumValue");
        }
    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Item1Description")]
    Item1,
    [Description("Item2Description")]
    Item2,
    [Description("Item3Description")]
    Item3,
    [Description("Item4Description")]
    Item4
}

public class PropertyChangedNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just saw that you want description, not name - I'll try modify my code in a bit to reflect your question a bit better.

Comment: Why in the world would you a tuple rather than dictionary.

Comment: You can do it either way - normally I would wrap the Tuple to expose properties with more descriptive names than 'Item1' and 'Item2' or 'Key.Name' and 'Value' in the case of a Dictionary so that the binding is more obvious without having to look a the ViewModel code.

Comment: Yea I'm not a fan of tuples if I don't have to. Appreciate the response though.