# How to display enum's [Description] in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I'm building an WPF application.

My DataGrid display rows with data from

```
ItemSrouce="{Bingding Accounts}"
```

in C#

```
accountListViewModel.Accounts = entityService.Accounts; // each record is an instance of Account class
```

The Account class have an Enum propery named Genders. The Enum like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("MyEnum1 Description")]
    MyEnum1,
    [Description("MyEnum2 Description")]
    MyEnum2,
    [Description("MyEnum3 Description")]
    MyEnum3
}
```

How to make my **DataGrid in WPF**  display the description instead of enum name ?

Comment: [GetEnumDescription](http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/enum/getenumdescription)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show Enum Description Instead of Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439920/show-enum-description-instead-of-name)

Answer (score 4):

You can create custom [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  for your cell binding and put in it logic for retrieving attribute value.

```
public class EnumDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private string GetEnumDescription(Enum enumObj)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = enumObj.GetType().GetField(enumObj.ToString());
        var descriptionAttr = fieldInfo
                                      .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                      .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
                                      .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
                                      .SingleOrDefault();
        if (descriptionAttr == null)
        {
            return enumObj.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return descriptionAttr.Description;
        }
    }

    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Enum myEnum = (Enum)value;
        string description = GetEnumDescription(myEnum);
        return description;
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()` is unnecessary. `OfType<T>` already returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're really asking for is a `TypeConverter`

For the `DataGrid` it is seemingly not enough to just have `EnumMember` or `Description` on your enumeration members decorated. It also wants to have the actual type to be decorated with a `[TypeConverter(typeof(YourConverter))]`. There exists an `EnumConverter` in ComponentModel, however it is not attribute aware - just 'ToString()'s the enum members.

Therefore my suggestion is:

This may be your enum:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
public enum ComparisonOperators
{
    [Description("=")]
    [EnumMember(Value = "=")]
    Equal,

    [Description("<>")]
    [EnumMember(Value = "<>")]
    Unequal,

    [Description("<")]
    [EnumMember(Value = "<")]
    LessThan,

    [Description("<=")]
    [EnumMember(Value = "<=")]
    LessThanOrEqual,

    [Description(">")]
    [EnumMember(Value = ">")]
    GreaterThan,

    [Description(">=")]
    [EnumMember(Value = ">=")]
    GreaterThanOrEqual
}
```

Then you need the mentioned `EnumDescriptionTypeConverter` (Note that it respects EnumMember and Description attributes in the same way):

```
    public class EnumDescriptionTypeConverter : EnumConverter
{
    public EnumDescriptionTypeConverter(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
                if (fi != null)
                {
                    var dattributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
                    var eattributes = (EnumMemberAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false);
                    return dattributes.Select(d => d.Description).Concat(eattributes.Select(e => e.Value))
                               .FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Then you just bind your ViewModel to the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Vm}" />
```

Auto generate being enabled, it will display all Enum members as comboboxes.

Example VM:

```
public class MyVm : ViewModelBase
{
    [DisplayName("Number")]
    [Description("Provide a number")]
    public int OrdinaaryOrdinal {get; set;}

    [DisplayName("Compare operator")]
    [Description("to do")]
    public ComparisonOperators Operator {get; set;}
    ...
```

et viola it is displayed as supposed:

[image: Grid running with that enum type.]

Ressoures:

- https://brianlagunas.com/localize-enum-descriptions-in-wpf/
- http://www.karmian.org/net-tips-tricks-examples-articles/enum-description-typeconverter

Answer (score 0):

You should use Enum Extenstion class or Value Converter to do this,

[wpf-databinding-enum-with-nice-descriptions](http://codecopy.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/wpf-databinding-enum-with-nice-descriptions/)