# How to Display a friendly enum name in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've noticed that the WPF DataGrid displays the Enum Name by default. This is great. But is there a way to display a more friendly name? i.e. Without these underscores in my case?

[image]

```
void ResultGrid_AutoGeneratingColumns(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.Column.GetType() == typeof(DataGridComboBoxColumn))
            {
                var binding = (e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn).TextBinding.StringFormat(...);
              //  binding.Converter = new EnumConverter();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This might get you started - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11440293/632337.

Comment: Essence is to set `Description` attribute over enum and get it either using `IValueConverter` or using `ObjectDataProvider` like provided in the sample above.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @Rohit I've done something similar to no success. The problem is that StringFormat is not flexible enough or if I go to access the binding directly im not allowed to. Instead I have to use binding base.

Comment: @gawicks why don't you use xaml?

Comment: I can try specifying the binding converter for each property one by one. But I want to do it across all enum types at once. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom IValueConverter to take your enum value and return a friendly string. This just does a simple string replace.

```
public class GeneralEnumConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.GetType().IsEnum)
        {
            return this.FormatEnumName(value.ToString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string FormatEnumName(string enumName)
    {
        return enumName.Replace('_', ' ');
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then your XAML will need a resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Converter:GeneralEnumConverter x:Key="GeneralEnumConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

You will need to define Converter in your XAML root element and point it to the namespace for your converter. This is a lot easier if done in Blend/Visual Studio XAML Designer as you can create a new converter from the 'Create Binding' menu.

Next apply the converter to your binding...

```
<Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Tag, Converter={StaticResource GeneralEnumConverter}, ElementName=label}" />
```

This is a hacky binding of a label to itself, the important part is the Converter= attribute.

Hope this helps.

Please mark as answer if so.

Comment: Nope this means I have to specify the converter for each property one by one. Im looking for a way to change how enums are represented across the board. Even If it means overriding DataGrid I'm fine with that.

Comment: You've only got two lists, what are all the properties?

Comment: This datagrid is actually a part of a custom control. I've no way to know which properties will be bound to this grid beforehand. Only thing I know is that some of them will be enums.That's why I need the formatting to be separated from the actual type of the enum

Comment: Make this more generic then by dropping the value type check and instead just do a string.replace on the ToString for whatever value is. Might end with funky results if used elsewhere but gives you a base line.

Comment: Better still add [Type.IsEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum(v=vs.110).aspx) to your convertor to only apply when an enumeration

Comment: Can you post me the xaml of that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57785/discussion-between-gawicks-and-kidshaw).